# Want Inno Setup to offer the option to create desktop shortcuts, but not Start menu shortcuts

Tags: inno-setup

My icons section is Inno Setup currently looks like this:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\Apps\Login"; Filename: "{sd}\exe\Logn.exe"
Name: "{userdesktop}\Apps\Pats"; Filename: "{sd}\exe\Pats.exe"
Name: "{userdesktop}\Apps\Str"; Filename: "{sd}\exe\Str.exe"
Name: "{userdesktop}\Apps\StrMng"; Filename: "{sd}\Odin\exe\StrMgr.exe"
```

During install, Inno has a 'Start Menu shortcuts' section. If I let Inno do its thing, it will install the shortcuts listed above but ALSO a start menu entry, with a bunch of exe's which I don't want. How to get Inno to only offer the option to add the shortcuts above, and not start menu shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the [`DisableProgramGroupPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disableprogramgrouppage) to `yes`:

```
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
```

---

Though even with the default `auto`, the installer won't create any icons in the Start menu on its own. If it does create some, you must have these icons in the `Icons` section.

Comment: The [icons] section I gave is the entirety of my icons section. Adding your option removes the page that asks whether you want to create start menu shortcuts, and creates the icon I requested without asking. Good enough for now.